# Play Harvest Moon without reading game guides and the like?

Tags: harvest-moon-gb

Yesterday I started to play Harvest Moon (the original game for Gameboy). I haven't played any Harvest Moon title before, but I've played some other similar titles like Animal Crossing and Viva Pinata.

There seem to be no real introductions (except that I can put things in the box to sell them). Do you think i should play it blind and just keep trying everything or should I read something about the gameplay or watch some videos on the internet to have the most fun?

Just to make it a little more clear:
Is there something I could do wrong that will screw up my Character / Savegame?
Is it possible, like in most MMORPGs, that if you dont know the classes you may start your character wrong (eg with wrong STAT's)?

Comment: What you should do is totally up to you.  Harvest Moon is one of the more relaxing games to play.  The only irreversible choice is which girl to marry.  Once you marry them, you're stuck with them.  So choose wisely.

Comment: 'The only irreversible choice is which girl to marry.'
This is what i wanted to hear, if you would post it as a answer i could accept it :D

Comment: Back in the day, [games came packaged with papery things called "manuals" that explained how to play the game](http://yardsellr.com/for_sale/harvest-moon-game-for-nintendo-game-boy-plus-instruction-manual--free-shipping-2429092), instead of having a programmed-in tutorial or introduction. The secret first quest of the game is to go find one of those in real life or in PDF. It's like an ARG! ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yes but its hard to find a manual for most of the old games now... i havent found one at the internet yet.
Ive only the manual for Donkey-Kong left but someone has stolen my game 10 years ago :/

Comment: Hm, well, I'm reading the manual right now, so the quest isn't impossible. You might have better luck if you know that the official title is *Harvest Moon GB*, and that *Harvest Moon GBC* is the same gameplay, just colourised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Harvest Moon plays more like a sandbox game (limited to your local area) more than anything else.  They tend to be short on tutorials, because the early games didn't really have much of a goal, beyond that which you set for yourself.  Even in the later ones, the goals are usually very generous, and give you plenty of time to meet them.  That gives you freedom to experiment without worrying you're screwing up your game.

The original game for SNES had a hard time limit, but you could abuse the fact that it didn't actually advance until you slept.  So it was easy to clear the field the very first day.

In essence, Harvest Moon is a time management simulation.  You can "succeed" by doing as much (or as little) as you want.  The only limiter is your stamina.  If you're going for pure efficiency, so you waste as little time as possible, then you're going to need to look online.  This, however, is definitely not a requirement.  Harvest Moon does not have missable items (although, some could require rather extensive effort and preparation in order to acquire), so there's no time crunch required so you don't miss anything.

The only restriction on irreversible choices are your marriage candidates.  Once you've married one of them, you can't get rid of them and choose someone else.  They're with you until death (or a save reset) do you part.  Note that there usually is a time limit on how long you have to court your chosen.  You have roughly four or five years before they marry their other option.  That's easily enough time to choose the one you want, and court them, and have several years to spare.  So the time limit is very generous.

Note that for your chosen game, I couldn't find any info on marrying anyone.  It may not be included in that one, in which case, there's nothing at all to worry about time-wise.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I find games most interesting if I have to find all things on my own. Just imagine the internet does not have the answers to help you and just explore and collect everything yourself. This is also the natural way that game-developers design and create the games. As @Sentry said this is exactly the way games are meant to be played and i couldn't agree more with him. Cheers, Marco

---

Additional information

---

Please note that games were not created to be impossible. If you cant think of a way to get past a part of the game do not give up after 5 minutes and search for an answer. Just keep on looking and (most of the time) you will find that the answer is relatively simpler than you initially thought.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely keep trying. It is much more fun that way. In my opinion it is boring to read and get special hints. Trying by yourself is a lot more fun. I do it this way all the time

EDIT: you can do everything wrong, but you only know AFTER you did ^^ don't be shy, just try it. And if you really get stuck we are there to hel you ^^

Comment: @Sentry yes most of the time..
but there are also some games you should't or can't play without studying it before(but most of the time these are mmorpg or rpgs with statting where you can upgrade the wrong stats if you dont know anything about the game(play)).

Comment: Er.... i am playnt aion and runes of magc and tought me everything myself ^^

Comment: @Ekonion so do you have/had a "first character" you screwed up with wrong stats?
e.G. as i started playing Flyff i screwed up my first character because this was somehow my first real MMORPG and this character is somehow unplayable now.
After that time i normally read some guides before i start a new Character in a game i havent played before.

Comment: @Vloxxity "first character" ? xD nope ^^ more kinda sixth or seventh character ^^ it took a lot of tries, but i think exactly that is the fun thereby

Comment: @Vloxxity i sually create one character of every class and try them all a bit, then i create new with the classes i luke and then i create some where i try to figure out what works the best with my char.... at runes od magic i have 5 accounts with a total of about 20 chars

Comment: @Ekonion I'm the other way arround, I do alot of research first before I pick seeing if i like the class, what the abilities are, what good stats for them are etc... once I finally made up my mind ill start playing. This means I don't have to do the same quest 20 times because I kept disliking the class or misstraining the character.

Comment: @Lyrion Yea, but your gameplay is based on the knowledge of the others.... if i already know everything, why should i play then? If theres nothin/less left to find out, wheres the fun? My opinion, not a personal attack. What do you play fantasy mmos for? One of mine main-points is that i am able to explore a new world, and find all its secrets, but if i read all about it at first this is badly possible. I would never play a real-life mmi, cuz this is something i already know... the interesting point is the unknown i think

Comment: @Ekonion Well yeah, I play the mmo's aswel to explore and get there along the way. But if you gimp your character and you can't advance until you buy a respec that costs tons of money and you don't have that yet, forcing you to start new. That is where the fun ends for me, that is why I research how to develop my character before actually starting. But the rest is still a mystery to me.

Comment: @Lyrion that is a good point, a point i can respect ^^ i think some will follow my thoughts, others yours ^^ tell me, what is yor target in playing mmos?

Comment: @Ekonion It all depends on the mmo, for example WoW was reaching end content and starting to raid, gw2 was going for the achievements, defiance is killing loads of stuff and doing all the missions to get the achievements. I also recently started play Daoc again and the focus there is doing loads of Realm vs Realm because it is great fun.

Comment: So your all-over-main-target is success, mine is only fun... i may never reach the end-content, but i have tons of fun ^^ so if you want success, you study before playing and if you just want to play for fun you easiely start ^^

Comment: I might misstold something, your primary target is success your secondary is fun, inverted to me... mine primary is fun and my secondary is success